# Window Type Aircon Upside down

Tags: air-conditioning

I'm not an AC Technician. I bought a new window type air-conditioner. My friend lifted it upside down.

Is it okay to lift or carry a window type air-conditioner upside down?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever I've purchased items that use refrigerant the manual always recommends leaving it to rest. Times have varied from 1 to 24 hours. The manual says this is to let the refrigerant settle after transit.

There is oil mixed in with the refrigerant that lubricates the compressor. If it's tipped over or turned upside down the refrigerant can move to other parts of the system. If you turn on the air conditioner in this condition it may not work or may even damage the unit. Set it in the correct position and wait 24 hours before using it. Realistically less than an hour should be fine but most manuals recommend 24 hours to be safe.

So no. Moving the air conditioner upside down won't damage it. If you try to run it too soon after it's been upside down that can damage it.

Answer (score 0):

After my air conditioner was delivered I took it upstairs to my bedroom and unpacked the unit. The unit was placed in the the proper position for two days before it was installed. After installing the unit it was turned on and is working like it should.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).